# How to find two same items in a python list

Tags: python, list

So I want to be able to check if a list in a python program contains a particular value written twice.

```
list_one = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
```

Here I want to check if two different items have the same value, for instance a == d

Comment: Kindly elaborate *two different items have the same value*. Provide code samples, examples and illustrate what exactly is not working for you

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through your list to see how many times each value appears. If `count()` evaluates to more than 1, you know there are duplicates of the current value.

```
for i in list_one:
    if i.count() > 1:
        print("Duplicate: " + i)
```

If you want to compare two values directly, you can use their indices. For example, in the case of `a == d`:

```
if list_one[0] == list_one[3]:
    print("a and d are equal.")
```

You can also use a function, like follows, to find all of the indexes that there are duplicates:

```
def getIndexPositions(listOfElements, element): #pass it the list and element to check for duplicates of
    ''' Returns the indexes of all occurrences of give element in
    the list- listOfElements '''
    indexPosList = []
    indexPos = 0
    while True:
        try:
            # Search for item in list from indexPos to the end of list
            indexPos = listOfElements.index(element, indexPos)
            # Add the index position in list
            indexPosList.append(indexPos)
            indexPos += 1
        except ValueError as e:
            break

    return indexPosLis
```

Answer (score 0):

This will check a list for duplicate values and produce a new list containing any values that were duplicated in the first list:

```
items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'a', 'c']
items.sort()
dups = [
    item1
    for item1, item2 in zip(items[:-1], items[1:])
    if item1 == item2
]
```